# Performance of multiple times SUM(fieldX) in a query

Tags: sql, performance, sum

I'm generating a big request in VB, and it can get quite big... and slow too.

I have 3 types of pieces (1,2,3) and I want the average humidity of a package of pieces
So a request's header looks like :

```
SELECT package.id,
CASE WHEN Sum(package.totalPce) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    Sum(nbTooHumid * package.totalPce) / Sum(package.totalPce) END as tooHumid,
```

Then I do the same with nbTooDry instead of nbTooHumid, and with HumidOk as a third one.

Plus, I calculate other fields too, divising by Sum(package.totalPce) too.

So, I call more or less 10 times :

```
Sum(package.totalPce)
```

and I'm wondering if it is one thing slowing my request down or not because
 my request is soo long its executing time vary between 5 sec and 2 minutes.

EDIT: A detail I'll add after reading gordon's answer.

I get the field nbTooHumid from a subrequest, and every packages that I want to get in the request have to be merged from the other ones with an UNION.

And the pieces table have millions of entries, so, yes, it's IO's problem.

And I'll add a more complete example so you can have a complete idea of what my request looks like.

```
SELECT package.id,
CASE WHEN Sum(package.totalPce) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    Sum(nbTooHumid * package.totalPce) / Sum(package.totalPce) END as tooHumid,
manyOtherFields
FROM 
((SELECT count(*) as totalPce, otherFields
FROM pieces 
WHERE idPackage = X and date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-11')
UNION
(SELECT ...)
)
```

Please note this is only the average format of my request and I didn't use the exact syntax or fields name.

Comment: Have you tried running your query in SSMS and looking at the Execution plan? This will likely give you pointers to where the bottle neck is.

Comment: Yes, Clustered table scan takes ± 33% and Table scan takes ± 56%.

The rest is splitted in 0% and 1% between hundreds of little executions (as Nested Loop for Inner Join... even if I DONT have a single inner join lol)

Comment: Actually, I wasn't really hoping to accelerate my 2 min long request to a coupple of seconds asking help here, I was just wondering if the multipple use of SUM was for something in it, seems not so I'm happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A performance question definitely depends on the database that you are using.

In general, though, numeric functions go much, much, much faster than the data manipulations required for the query.  So, I really doubt that this is the performance problem.

A highly variable execution time suggests one of two things.  Either the server being used is busy, slowing down your query.  In this case, you can't do much about slow queries.  The second is when the longer run is the first run, and then it goes faster.  This is because the database is loading tables in cached memory.  It doesn't have to perform the I/O for subsequent queries.

However, you should post your entire query if you really want help with the performance.

Comment: Thanks,
The reason of my problem is the second one you gave.

And I wont post my entire query because 1- I'm not sure my boss would want to.
and 2- it can become pages long...